# #1050 - Table 'batch' already exists on importing through mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am recieving this error below on importing a new .sql. Kindly help resolve. I am importing in to new Data Base.

**Error**

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `batch` (
  `bid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique batch ID.',
  `token` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'A string token generated against the current user''s session id and the batch id, used to ensure that only the user who submitted the batch can effectively access it.',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when this batch was submitted for processing. Stale batches are purged at cron time.',
  `batch` longblob COMMENT 'A serialized array containing the processing data for the batch.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Stores details about batches (processes that run in…'
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1050 - Table 'batch' already exists
```

Comment: `drop table if exists`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to drop the table and lose any potential data in there, simply adjust your create query to begin like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop the table first, maybe you've already made the table.